# Достать геоданные асинхронно

Tags: javascript, json, геолокация

есть фрагмент кода, который возвращает геоданные пользователя(широта, долгота) в таком варианте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как отсюда можно вытащить только широту и долготу?

```js
function getCurrentLocation(options) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, ({code, message}) =>
  reject(Object.assign(new Error(message), {name: "PositionError", code})),
  options);
  });
 };
 async function inout() {
  try {
   console.log(await this.getCurrentLocation({
   enableHighAccuracy: true,
   timeout: 5000,
   maximumAge: 0
   }));
  } catch (e) {
   if (e.name == 'PositionError') {
   console.log(e.message + ". code = " + e.code);
   }
  }
 };
 inout().catch(e => console.log(e)); // User denied geolocation prompt. code = 1
```

Comment: а что значит достать? можно же сохранить результат в переменную например, let location = await this. getCurrentLocation(...); и уже потом location.coords.latitude, или вопрос в чем-то другом?

Comment: await this. getCurrentLocation(...); приходит ответ ввиде Promise в нем есть PromiseValue который я хочу получить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как отсюда можно вытащить только широту и долготу?

Если в отдельные const-переменные (`latitude` и `longitude`):

```
const {
  coords: { latitude, longitude }
} = await this.getCurrentLocation();
```

Если в новый объект (`obj`):

```
const obj = { ...({
  latitude, longitude
} = (await this.getCurrentLocation()).coords) }; 

// или

const obj = { ...({
  coords: { latitude, longitude }
} = await this.getCurrentLocation()) }.coords;
```

---

Эти выражения будут работать только внутри `async` метода, конечно же.

Comment: Вариант "в новый объект" == вынос мозга.